# php mysql compare int and time

Tags: php, mysql

i need to compare name of column in db with current time interval. Intervals are in half hour (7:00, 7:30, 8:00 etc.) and my coumn name is set (7:00, 7:30, 8:00 etc.) So i am trying to compare those two thing wtih IF function.

I have this query: (example for 7:00 coumn name)

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM  msa_intervali");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['7:00'];
    }
}
```

is it possible to compare colmun name with time?

Comment: column names like `7:00,7:300`? worst db design.You need to change structure as soon as possible

Comment: It is, but it does make me think that you have made a basic mistake when designing your database

Comment: hahah ok, but how can i compare current interval with interval set in db. I will change db structure but i dont have idea how.

Comment: The point of all of this is to have some number output based on current interval, please help with some logic about this

Comment: You did a fetch_assoc so you have an assoc array. like `7:00 => a_value` so you can `foreach ($row as $colName => $colValue)`

Comment: any sample data, the question seems a bit unclear?

Comment: @AlivetoDie so if i understand correct,  i need line columns for example 'ID' 'Intervals' 'Intervals_ID' and set number in 'Intervals_ID' for each interval? Then i compare current time with that 'Interval_ID' (i need so many IF's)

Comment: Actually it depends on what you are trying to save in table and is this table going to be related to any other table through primary and foreign key concept or not

Comment: @AlivetoDie in that table i will have only one row, i will not save any data to it. it will be just a reference. So for example i interval 7:00 - 7:30 i need to dispaly number 5, in interval  7:30 to 8:00 i need to display number 2 etc

Comment: @Wils sampe data is in table i have columns 'ID','many intervals from 7:00 to 23:00' and in rows i have only 1 row with numbers (etc. 5,7,2,6,5) I need to compare current time interval with that fixed interval and display number from that column.